# Read server time from AWS DynamoDb, swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I need to get the current server time/timestamp from AWS dynamodb to my ios swift application.

In firebase db we can write the current timestamp to db and after that we can read it from the app. Any suggestion about this is appreciated.

Comment: Hey, did the answer end up working for you? If it did, you should accept it so that other SO users know that it solves the problem. If you had to tweak a few things or if you used a different solution, leave a comment or add your own answer to share that knowledge with others.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB does not provide any sort of server time—any timestamps must be added by the client. That being said, you can emulate a server time behavior by setting up a Lambda function or an EC2 instance as a write proxy for DynamoDB and have it add a timestamp to anything being written to DynamoDB. But it’s actually even easier than that.

AWS allows you to use [API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html) to act as a proxy to many AWS services. The process is a little long to explain in detail here, but there is an in-depth [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/) you can follow for setting up a proxy for DynamoDB. The short version is that you can create a rest endpoint, choose “AWS Service Proxy” as the integration type, and apply a transformation to the request that inserts the time of the request (as seen by API Gateway). The exact request mapping you set up will depend on how you want to define the REST resources and on the tables you are writing to. There is a [request context variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) that you can use to get the API Gateway server time. It is `$context.requestTimeEpoch`.